# How to do a Self-Referencing Many-to-Many Relationship in Bookshelf

Tags: javascript, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to work out the most expressively clear and "correct" way in [Bookshelf.Js](http://bookshelfjs.org) of setting up a many-to-many relationship for a User model to build-out the standard followers/followed relationship that exists on many social applications. The documentation in Bookshelf is throwing me for a loop, though.

I can see two possible approaches: 1) Using `belongsToMany()` alone, or 2) Using `belongsToMany()` with a `throught()`. Neither have worked for me, but let me show you first what I'm doing for (1). I start with this Model setup:

```
const User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('creating', this.encryptPassword);
  },
  hasTimestamps: true,
  posts: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Posts, 'author');
  },
  comments: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Comments);
  },
  following: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(UserFollow, 'users_users', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
  },
  followers: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(UserFollow, 'users_users', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
  },
});
```

And to match that I have a knex migration that adds a `users_users` table like so:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('users_users', (tbl) => {
    tbl.integer('user_id').references('users.id');
    tbl.integer('follower_id').references('users.id');
    tbl.unique(['user_id', 'follower_id']);  
      // This b/c I read a few places that Bookshelf might require a composite key.
  });
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('users_users');
};
```

Then I have the following test:

```
it('User model can record a follower', (done) => {
    const saveUsr = (data) => {
      return User.forge().save(data, {transacting: transaction});
    };
    Promise.all([saveUsr(mockUser), saveUsr(anotherMockUser)])
      .then((results) => {
        let usr1 = results[0];
        let usr2 = results[1];
        return usr2.followers().attach(usr1.id, {transacting: transaction});
      })
      .then((usrWithFollower) => {
        return usrWithFollower.fetch({
          withRelated: ['followers'],
          transacting: transaction
        });
      })
      .then((usr) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(usr));
        console.log('followers: ', usr.get('followers'));
        done();
      })
      .catch((err) => { done(err); });
   });
```

I'm not really testing much here as I've not been able to get the thing, working, but the result of `JSON.stringify(user)` in the last promise then callback is the following:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Sally Low",
      "username":"sally",
      "email":"sally@example.org",
      "created_at":"2016-06-05T15:24:41.835Z",
      "updated_at":"2016-06-05T15:24:41.835Z",
      "password":"$2a$10$613tL/baML9obsRN4Yg7MeU/2RiH7oK/nFUwfpQ1GYuA15VUFrFZu",
      "followers": [],
      "_pivot_user_id":2,
      "_pivot_follower_id":1
   }
]
```

As you can see, it looks as if some sort of relation has been setup here given that there are these `_pivot_` props, but what they are is not clear to me, and I'm not sure why the `followers` field is coming back empty.

If anyone can set me straight here or illuminate the situation in any way, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose those `UserFollow` models to be `User` aliases. This is not needed.

Try adding the [Registry Plugin](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry) and write your `User` model as:

```
const User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  // ...
  following: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany('User', 'users_users', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
  },
  followers: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany('User', 'users_users', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
  },
});
bookshelf.model('User', User);
```

The `attach()` code may use a model directly, no need to use the `id`:

```
usr2.followers().attach(usr1);
```

I made a minimal version of your schema and tried:

```
new User({name: 'Bia'}).
  fetch({withRelated: 'followers'}).
  then((m) => {console.log(m.toJSON());});
```

That gave me back:

```
{ name: 'Bia',
   id: 3,
   followers: 
    [ { id: 1, name: 'Ana', _pivot_user_id: 3, _pivot_follower_id: 1 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Mia', _pivot_user_id: 3, _pivot_follower_id: 2 } ] }
```